Number of iterations in simulated annealing regression model
I am new to applying the machine learning models. I am trying to apply a simulated annealing regression model. The question now is should I set up the iteration numbers in the regression control and the simulated annealing control or both of them?
The code is as following:
# Set up the parallel backend
Mycluster <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 2)  # Use available cores minus 2
registerDoParallel(Mycluster)  # Register for parallel execution

stime = system.time({
# Regression control for train function
reg.ctrl <- trainControl(method = "LOOCV", 
                         number = 100, 
                         repeats = 5, 
                         allowParallel = TRUE)

# Simulated annealing control setup
safs.ctrl <- safsControl(functions = caretSA, 
                         method = "LOOCV", 
                         number = 100,
                         metric = c(internal = "RMSE", external = "RMSE"),
                         maximize = c(internal = FALSE, external = FALSE),
                         holdout = 0.2, 
                         improve = 5,
                         allowParallel = TRUE, 
                         verbose = TRUE)

# Simulated annealing feature selection
sa_100 <- safs(x = MEs[, 1:dim(MEs)[[2]]],
           y = gsva[1, ],
           iters = 100, 
           metric = "RMSE",
           trControl = reg.ctrl,
           safsControl = safs.ctrl)
})[3]

stime[1] 

# Stop the cluster after computation is done
stopCluster(Mycluster)
registerDoSEQ()  # Reset to sequential execution

I mean, should I set the argument of number = 100 in functions of trainControl() and safsControl() or one of them? or just use iters = 100 in function of safs()?
In addition, I need to understand, What is the difference between the control of regression and the control of the simulated annealing?
